# dependency injection into view model class in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, model-validation, ivalidatableobject

I am using the following DTO class in one of my api controller class, in an asp.net core application.

```
public class InviteNewUserDto: IValidatableObject
{
  private readonly IClientRepository _clientRepository;

  public InviteNewUserDto(IClientRepository clientRepository)
  {
    _clientRepository = clientRepository;
  }

  //...code omitted for brevity
}
```

This is how I using it in a controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] InviteNewUserDto  model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

  //...omitted for brevity

}
```

But I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` in the DTO class
This is happening since **dependency injection** is not working in the DTO class.
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DI` will not resolve dependences for `ViewModel`.

You could try `validationContext.GetService` in `Validate` method.

```
public class InviteNewUserDto: IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IClientRepository repository = (IClientRepository)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IClientRepository));

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I made a small adjustment to code:
`var repository = validationContext.GetService<IClientRepository>();`; I was looking at IModelBinder solutions, but this is clever and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register ClientRepository in startup.cs?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   // asp.net DI needs to know what to inject in place of IClientRepository
   services.AddScoped<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();

   ...
}
```